# Score estimates are going out of boundaries

Tags: r, linear-regression

I conducted a survey that asks people to rate a restaurant on a scale of 1 to 7, and used individual regression results of coefficients to estimate the score of two new restaurants

```
results<- NULL #Set a new variable to stack
for(i in 1:6){
  results<-rbind(results,coef(lm(score~alcohol+type+price,d1[d1$id==i,])))
}
```

which result in

```
     (Intercept) alcoholY typericenoodle price12000
[1,]        3.50     3.00  -5.000000e-01       1.00
[2,]        2.50     3.00   5.000000e-01       1.50
[3,]        4.25     1.00  -5.000000e-01       1.00
[4,]        4.50    -0.50  -1.030373e-16       1.50
[5,]        7.00    -0.50  -5.000000e-01      -2.50
[6,]        4.25    -1.75  -2.500000e-01       2.75
```

I want to utilize this

```
case1<-c(1,1,1,1) #First option
case2<-c(1,0,0,0) #Second option
pred_score <- cbind(results%*%case1,results%*%case2)
results
head(pred_score,n=6) #CheckData, we can see the predicted scores 
for each individual
summary(pred_score)
apply(pred_score,1,which.max)
table(apply(pred_score,1,which.max))/6 #table for market share . 
prediction
barplot(table(apply(pred_score,1,which.max))/6,main='Market . 
Share',ylab='Share') #Bar plot for market share prediction
```

But the results (estimate score of individuals) are going out of the boundaries of 1 to 7

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 7.00 3.50
[2,] 7.50 2.50
[3,] 5.75 4.25
[4,] 5.50 4.50
[5,] 3.50 7.00
[6,] 5.00 4.25
```

Any help would be greatful!

Comment: *"and used individual regression results of coefficients"* Where is the code for the regression model? I have a feeling that this is where the issue lies. scale seems to be an *ordinal* variable. Did you take that into consideration when fitting your model? What kind of model did you use? I assume this has to be some form of ordinal logistic regression model.

Comment: The 'results' object is missing from your example code. I also don't see any regression going on here.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I added the individual regression model that i conducted to get the results!

Comment: @bstrain I added the results part of the code! Thanks

Comment: @viatmincode Ok, so the issue is the model. You're fitting a simple linear model `score ~ alcohol+type+price` to your data, which makes certain assumptions (continuous dependent variable, residuals are normally distributed, etc.). This is obviously not the case for your data (dependent variable is *ordinal*, residuals are not normal). So provided you want to do some form of inference on the data you collected, you will need to take a step back, and fit a suitable model to your data. I suggest reviewing (ordinal) logistic regression and/or multinomial regression models.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks so much, you really cleared things up for me. I haven't studied ordinal logistic regression yet, and I realized that my interpretation needs to utilize it!

Comment: No worries @viatmincode. Take a look at the `MASS` package and specifically the function `polr`. It allows you to fit a a logistic regression model to an ordered factor response. Perhaps a starting point for the model could be `MASS::polr(score ~ alcohol + type + price, data = df)`.